# How to find center of mass of a set of vectors?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

So, I have a set of position vectors (points, essentially). How can I find the "center of mass" of these points? Summing them all and then dividing by the number of points doesn't seem to work. I'm using Java, but any help would be appreciated, this is hardly a language specific question.

Edit: Ok, sounds like i wasn't clear enough. Each point is weighted the same, and I want to find the center of this group of points. When I average them by hand I get the right answer, but when I try to do it the same way in the program it gives an answer about 10-20% too big. I'm trying to make a flocking algorithm. Here is the bit that should calculate the centroid of all of the boids. flock.boidlist is a ArrayList of Boids, position is a Vector field of each boid. My Vector class has functions for addition and scalar multiplication

```
c=new Vector(0,0);
for(Boid b: flock.boidList){
        c.x+=b.position.x;
    c.y+=b.position.y;

    }
c.x=c.x/flock.boidList.size();
c.y=c.y/flock.boidList.size();
```

Comment: Define "center of mass" -- the centroid?

Comment: This sounds like a maths question, not a Java question.  Summing and dividing is finding the mean of the points, which sounds like a reasonable definition of the centre of mass.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: Never say "doesn't work" if you're not prepared to explain *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not an average, it's a weighted average, where the weight factor of each point is its associated mass. Perhaps you're not multiplying each point by its mass?

Comment: @Oli The center of mass doesn't have reasonable or unreasonable definitions. It has *the* definition.  ;-) For a collection of point masses, each of equal mass, the arithmetic mean of their positions is indeed equal to the center of mass.

Comment: Normally, when you say something that adds up to "my code doesn't work", you are expected to post the code in question.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was a dumb question, and I didn't describe the issue well at all. My problem is in my own code or my misunderstanding of how lwjgl works. Please close this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my understanding this is what you're looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points. Averaging the points should work, can you explain how it failed?